# Getting date from SQL Server using users input through winform

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-express

I'm supposed to take date from the user and then find all dates before that date.

```
DateTime dat = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
string datS = dat1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string query = "SELECT * FROM test3table WHERE datum" + 
                  " <= " + "datum LIKE '%' + @Datum + '%'";
// '2017-12-06'   -> works fine
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", datS);
```

Is something wrong with syntax or it cant be done this way?

Comment: where do you execute the query.. edit this to show all relevant code also do a google search on how to construct proper parameterized query also read up on the follow when using Dates `>= <= and Between` `LIKE` is a key word that works best for `Strings or Characters` not dates

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Steve's query resolved my issue. I will look into these things you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        DateTime dat = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;

        string query = "SELECT * FROM test3table WHERE datum <= @Datum";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", dat );
```

Change your column type to `DateTime` to save yourself some trouble converting into string and back. Then you can just do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query has incorrect syntax.  I believe what you need is this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM test3table WHERE datum" +
               " < '" + @Datum + "'";
```

This should construct a SQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test3table WHERE datum < '2017-12-06'
```

Note that I changed your `<=` operator to `<` to match your stated need for "all dates before that date".

Also remember that if `datum` is of type `DATETIME`, then a date value will be evaluated with a time of midnight.  So `2017-12-06` is read as `2017-12-06 00:00`.